# Orientability of a Lie group as manifold

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, orientation

Let $U$ be the set $U$ of quaternions of unit length. I know that $U\times S^1$ is compact, connected and is a $2n$ manifold in a $2n+1$ dimensional vector space $V$.

> I want to show that any Lie group is orientable. How can I construct an explicit orientation?

Comment: $U\times S^1$ is indeed a $4$-dimensional manifold. But what $5$-dimensional vector space is it supposed to be contained in?

Comment: @JackLee Is it 4 dimensional? Not 6?

Comment: $U$ is diffeomorphic to $S^3$, hence $3$-dimensional. $S^1$ is $1$-dimensional. So the product is $4$-dimensional.

Comment: @JackLee My textbook says $U\times S^1\subset\mathbb{R}^6$

Comment: Yes, that's true. But you started your question by saying that $U\times S^1$ is a $2n$-manifold in a $(2n+1)$-dimensional vector space. In this case, $2n=4$, so $2n+1$ would be $5$. But $\mathbb R^6$ is not $5$-dimensional.

Comment: @JackLee What could the 5-dimensional vector space be then?

Comment: I have no idea. Why do you think there is one?

Comment: @JackLee Because my textbook said so. Could you construct a tangent vector field without knowing such a vector space?